# Dart list added to another list becomes empty when emptying the first list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below user defined objects -

```
class PhoneBookContact {
  String? phoneBookContact;
  List<ContactNumber>? contactNumbers;

  PhoneBookContact(this.phoneBookContact, this.contactNumbers);
}

class ContactNumber {
  String phone;
  bool availableOnBol;

  ContactNumber(this.phone, this.availableOnBol);
}
```

In my main method I am creating a list for the ContactNumber class and then later adding that ContactNumber list to the contactNumbers property of PhoneBookContact list. This is all done inside of a for loop.

The issue I am having is when I am clearing the contactNumbers list after adding those items to the contactNumbers property of the PhoneBookContact list, I see those cleared from the PhoneBookContact list as well, which I find weird, or maybe I am not thinking it the right way.

```
  List<PhoneBookContact> phoneBookContacts = [];
    List<ContactNumber> contactNumbers = [];

    for (var contact in contacts) {
      contactNumbers.clear();
      if (contact.phones.isNotEmpty) {
        for (var phone in contact.phones) {
          if (true) {
            contactNumbers.add(ContactNumber(phone.number, true));
          } else {
            contactNumbers.add(ContactNumber(phone.number, false));
          }
        }
      }
      phoneBookContacts
          .add(PhoneBookContact(contact.displayName, contactNumbers));
    }
```

Comment: You don't get flagged by your IDE that the `else` clause is unreachable code?

Comment: Not seeing any flags.

Comment: There is a very long expression, which I took it off for easy reading of the code.

Comment: It does in mine. Provide the type and declaration for the variable `contacts`.

Comment: simply move `List<ContactNumber> contactNumbers = [];` inside the outer `for (var contact in contacts) {` loop (of course you dont need `contactNumbers.clear();` then) - in that case `contactNumbers` is a new list every time the `for` statement loops

Comment: @pskink can you put it as an answer. That worked, but still confused why the clear at the same spot didn't do what was expected.

Comment: more here https://suragch.medium.com/cloning-lists-maps-and-sets-in-dart-d0fc3d6a570a

Comment: simply you are clearing the contactNumbers list before adding them to property.

Comment: @Mohammed_7aafar I am adding it to the main list at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PhoneBookContact constructor does not *make a copy* of the list. It takes a reference to the list and remembers it.

Since you *clear* the list every loop but *reuse* the same list instance, all your PhoneBookContacts will have the *same* list.

Lets clean up your method a little:

```
List<PhoneBookContact> phoneBookContacts = [];

for (var contact in contacts) {
  List<ContactNumber> contactNumbers = [];

  for (var phone in contact.phones) {
      final condition = true; // should be your complicated expression        

      contactNumbers.add(ContactNumber(phone.number, condition));
  }

  phoneBookContacts.add(PhoneBookContact(contact.displayName, contactNumbers));
}
```

Apart from removing some clutter, it makes sure that each loop, you instantiate a new list so that each PhoneBookContact *has it's own list*.

Comment: not to mention that `contactNumbers` is not needed at all if (instead of `for (var phone in contact.phones) {` loop) `contact.phones.map(...).toList()` is used

Comment: That is true, the whole thing could be two nested maps, but that might be a little over the current level of the OP.